# C++:confusion about converting constructor when using the result as parameter of a member function

Tags: c++, c++11

The problem is based on C++ primer 5th edition7.49
I have a class and have defined its converting constructor:

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<vector>
    using namespace std;
    class Sales_data{
    public:
        Sales_data(const string&s):bookNo(s) {}
        //other constructor…………
        Sales_data& combine(const Sales_data&);
        private:
        string bookNo;
        unsigned units_sold = 0;
        double revenue = 0.0;
    };
    Sales_data& Sales_data::combine(const Sales_data &rhs)
    {
        units_sold+=rhs.units_sold;
        revenue+=rhs.revenue;
        return *this;
    }
    int main()
    {
        string s("No.1");
        Sales_data item1("No.1");
        item1.combine(s);
        return 0;
    }
```

The code performs well,but if I change the declaration of a member function:combine,something ambiguous happen.

```
    Sales_data& combine(Sales_data&);
```

compile error:no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string}’ to ‘Sales_data&’

```
    Sales_data& combine(Sales_data);
```

No error is reported when compiling.
I know the string object s can convert to a Sales_data object like:

```
   Sales_data temp(s);
   item1.combine(temp);
```

But I am pretty confused of the parameter type needed in member function:combine. Hope for your help!

Comment: When you pass a `string` to `combine()`, a temporary `Sales_data` object is created. A temporary can't bind to a non-const reference - hence the error.

Comment: Your code is already correct, no need to change it

Answer (score 2):

For `item1.combine(s);`, a temporary variable of type `Sales_data` will be created as the argument, so

```
Sales_data& combine(const Sales_data&); // ok, a temporary can be used as an initializer for a const reference
Sales_data& combine(Sales_data&); // error, a temporary can't be used as an initializer for a non-const reference
Sales_data& combine(Sales_data); // ok, the temporary variable will be copied
```

Basically, a temporary object is destroyed at the end of the full expression in which it was created, but after bound to a reference, the temporary will be destroyed when the reference go out of scope.

For your case, `rhs` is an input-only parameter, so no need to use a non-const reference, and pass by const reference can avoid unnecessary copy in comparison with pass by value, so `Sales_data& combine(const Sales_data&);` is best here.

Answer (score 0):

From this code: `Sales_data& combine(Sales_data);` a new temporary `Sales_data` will be made and it will copy the values of the `Sales_data` parameter that has been passed so it's fine. The temporary will expire once the function ends.

`Sales_data& combine(Sales_data&);` this code takes up an existing `Sales_data` and refer to it. It can't take rvalues(values that has no variable identifier).

In order for it to accept an `rvalue` it must be either declared as `const Sales_data& rhs` or `Sales_data&& rhs`